# Hide page extension and table names in url

Tags: .htaccess, asp-classic, web-config

How do i hide my page extension for example

```
 mysite.com/index.asp
```

how do i take off the extension .asp

and also how i hide tables field names in a URL. example is I'm displaying details of a record of 2 . so the link is going to be

```
mysite.com/details?record_id=2
```

how do i take off the `record_1d=2` to make it

```
mysite.com/details
```

I'm working with asp classic.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You want this:

http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite

Your rule would look like this:

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="RewriteASP">
            <match url="(.*)" />
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}.asp" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

As far as I'm aware you can't rewrite the querystrings without retooling your code to pass data via HTTP posts.